# Volume of solid under plane $4x-2y+z = 18$ and above the region bounded by $4x+y = 16$ and $x^{2}+y = 16$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Express the volume of the solid under the plane $4x-2y+z = 18$ and above the region bounded by $4x+y = 16$ and $x^{2}+y = 16$.

Can't determine lower y boundary!

Volume = $\displaystyle \int_0^4\int_0^{16-x^2} 18 -4x + 2y\,dy\,dx$

For some reason volume doesn't start being integrated from y = $0$.

Why?? It clearly should, judging by the [quick sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRLMj.jpg).

You basically need that red-shaded region (and then imagine there's a plane above that red-shaded region).

So y definitely starts from $0$... why not?

I mean, when x = $4$, y = $0$, no?

Comment: The region of integration is bounded below by the straight line $y=16-x$ and above by the parabola $y=16-x^2$ so the lower limit of $y$ is the line $y=16-4x$ not the line $y=0$. Remember that the limits on an integral are actually abbreviated equations.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales it's funny that for x boundary, you can just look from what x and to which x there's region, e.g. from x = 0 to x = 4. There's no integrated region on x = 5. But for "y" axis you have to use equations...

Comment: In the $x$ direction the region of integration is that portion of the region lying between the graphs of $y=16-4x$ and $y=16-x^2$ that *also* lies between the two vertical lines $x=0$ and $x=4$. In this problem those happen to be the two vertical lines needed since those come from the intersection of the two curves. But the problem could have been different. It might have required, for example, that $1\le x\le 2$, then the outer integral would have been between the vertical lines $x=1$ and $x=2$. The limits on integrals *always* represent equations. Many teachers fail to mention this fact.

Comment: It is considered a courtesy to upvote an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the graph of the region of integration.

[Region bounded by graphs of $y=16-4x$ and $y=16-x^2$](http://fooplot.com/plot/thke7qkjcy)

Thus the lower limit should be $y=16-4x$ not $y=0$.